# Proving $\cos(a+b)=\cos a\cdot\cos b - \sin a\cdot\sin b$

Tags: trigonometry

I would like to prove the following $$\cos(a+b)=\cos a\cdot\cos b - \sin a\cdot\sin b.$$

Comment: You can try to use $$\cos x=\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}2$$ and evaluate it in $x=a+b$.

Comment: Yes we can ;o) But the way to do it depends on your definition of trigonometric functions

Comment: Geometric proofs [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1459456/prove-geometrically-that-cosab-cosa-cosb-sina-sinb?rq=1).

Answer (score 1):

Euler's formula states that
$$e^{ix} = \cos(x)+i\sin(x)$$
Then
$$e^{(a+b)i} = \cos(a+b) + i\sin(a+b)$$
but the above is also equal to
$$e^{ai}e^{bi}=(\cos(a)+i\sin(a))(\cos(b)+i\sin(b)) =$$$$ (\cos(a)\cos(b)-\sin(a)\sin(b)) + i(\cos(a)\sin(b)+\sin(a)\cos(b))$$
And so the corresponding components are equal.