# Proof that $\cos^2(\theta) \sin^2(\theta) = \dfrac{1}{4}\sin^2(2\theta)$.

Tags: trigonometry

I recently came across the identity $\cos^2(\theta) \sin^2(\theta) = \dfrac{1}{4}\sin^2(2\theta)$.

I was wondering if someone could please take the time to prove that this is true (or link to a proof)?

Comment: This is the _double-angle formula_ for sine ($\sin 2x = 2\sin x \cos x$), squared. If you search for that name, you'll find proofs.

Comment: Do you want to use something other than the square of the double angle formula: $\sin(2\theta)=2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)$?

Comment: Ahh, I got it now. Thank you all!

Comment: I'm wondering what have you tried to prove this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the fact that $$\sin(a+b)=\sin(a)\cos(b)+\sin(b)\cos(a)\tag{E}$$
you get

$$\sin(2\theta )=2\cos(\theta )\sin(\theta ).$$

You can find a geometrical proof of $(\text{E})$  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1459456/prove-geometrically-that-cosab-cosa-cosb-sina-sinb).

Comment: thanks for the link ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Many ways how to do this: Ex: $\sin2\alpha=2\sin{\alpha}\cos\alpha$ (standard identity) so squaring gives $\sin^2{2\alpha}=4{\sin^2\alpha}\cos^2\alpha$. Now divide by $4$

Comment: MathJax hint:  if you put a backslash before common functions you get the proper font and spacing, so \sin 2\alpha gives $\sin 2 \alpha$ instead of $sin2\alpha$

Comment: @RossMillikan Thanks!